# Get "Cookie" from https site by curl

Tags: wget, curl, https, cookie

I would like to have cookie of a HTTPS site.
I do have credential and certificate to access given site.

If I access site from chrome/firefox then I can easily extract cookie but what is the way to have this cookie from command line by using curl,wget or similar CUI-based tools ?

Answer (score 4):

Try this out:

```
curl -c - '<website>'
```

- -c flag is to retrieve the cookie

Comment: curl: no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information

Comment: What command did you use? Can you copy and the paste the exact command?

Comment: I used the same command as you mentioned by replacing '<website>' by desired URL.

Comment: I made a typo in my answer.. Just updated

Comment: I tried that too. Then message appears as "<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>"

Comment: Can i try testing with the URL your are plugging in? Or is this a private site?

Comment: This is private site. Or more precisely, it's in LAN only.

Comment: Ok, I am testing google's site. I am making sure to plug in http and www in front of google.com